# Getting null value from documents in Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

hey guys i am trying to get a text from firestore but it is returning a null value. did the same for firebase database so i know i am the doing something wrong, so please if you have a solution or you find a mistake i made kindly comment.

this is the query the firestore

```
private var query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        .collection("available")
        .limit(50)
```

this is the option

```
val options = FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Available_List>()
        .setQuery(query, Available_List::class.java)
        .build()
```

this is the RecyclerAdapter and it works

```
private var firebaseRecyclerAdapter = object : FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Available_List, AvailableViewHolder>(options) {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AvailableViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.available, parent, false)

        return AvailableViewHolder(view)
    }
```

this is where i get the null value **model.mAvailable.isNullOrEmpty()** is true

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AvailableViewHolder, position: Int, model: Available_List) {

        Toast.makeText(this@Searching,model.mAvailable.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        if (model.mAvailable.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Log.d("model testing","true")
        }else{
            Log.d("model testing","false")
        }

        holder.available.text = model.mAvailable
    }
}
```

this is my class

```
class AvailableList {
    var mAvailable:String? = null

    constructor(){}


    constructor(available:String){
        this.mAvailable = available
    }
}
```

if you have a solution in java, would also be nice!!!

[image: firestore database]

Answer (score 0):

Your `AvailableList` defines a single field with the name `mAvailable`. Since your documents only contain a field named `available`, the objects Firebase creates from the documents will be empty.

To allow Firebase to read the documents, make sure the field names in the documents match the names in your class.